# PenTesting - Configuring vulnerabilities on XP SP 1/2/3 & Server 2008

Tags: penetration-test, windows-xp

I've been creating test ranges using VMWare and an isolated network to play around with, and configuring endpoint workstations to be the receiving end of penetration tests.

I've found that the "easy" exploits are ms03_026_dcom and ms08_067_netapi, but of course I want to expand my configuration horizons so I am trying to configure other holes in the workstations.

I've tried configuring IIS Web & FTP servers to be extremely insecure (ended up with IIS 5.1 and 6.0 I believe) but found none of the exploits I tried worked.

Question: What are some good vulnerable services, 3rd party software, or configuration settings I can try that stray from plain old RPC and SMB?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend combining a search of Metasploit modules with software from [Oldversion](http://www.oldversion.com/) as being a good starting point for this kind of research.

You can search Metasploit based on exploit reliability and then see if you can find the appropriate software version on the site.

Another option would be to look at some of the pen test/CTF labs for the kinds of exploits they line up.

Answer (score 0):

You are only interested in windows lab?? you can find a really good lab configuration over the book the hacker´s handbook 2 using windows server 2012 and more reliable technologies. in linux there is a project   called metasploitable from rapid7 and its a old ubuntu server with many vulnerabilitys and back doors [metasploitable link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/metasploitable/files/Metasploitable2/)

Comment: I do have a Metasploitable range already! But that is good advice so thank you. I am focusing on Windows right now because I've already got some good Linux systems (Fedora, Ubuntu, FreeBSD) set up.

Comment: ok , give the hacker handbook a try , the lab its really good , you will have much more newer systems [link to the book](http://www.amazon.com/Hacker-Playbook-Practical-Penetration-Testing/dp/1512214566/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1456972331&sr=8-1&keywords=hacker+handbook+2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try "[ms15_034](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/auxiliary/dos/http/ms15_034_ulonglongadd)_ulonglongadd" module in Metasploit.

This relatively new DOS exploit works against Microsoft's IIS causing the host OS to crash and display the famous  blue screen of death.